OneApi 2021 with Visual Studio 2019 not working in 1 out of 6 pcs (Windows 11 in all)
I need to use OneAPI 2021 and VS2019 because the huge fortran model I am using only compiles on those, not more recent versions. I have  the OneAPI 2021 and vs2019 installers. I have a procedure that has worked on 5 computers but not my laptop. Unlike the other 5 computers, my laptop had OneAPI 2024 installed. I was not able to remove it, because when I was clicking on uninstall, it would say there was nothing to uninstall or something along those lines (see screenshot below, that is with the 2021 installed, no 2024 shows up after clicking uninstall). When I install OneApi 2021 basekit and HPCkit, I get the errors in the logs below. When I open Visual Studio, fortran compiler is not there. I tried to uninstall everything, to rename "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI" to C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI_backup, delete a couple of environmental variables named OneAPI_2024 and reinstall everything but still same result. Any suggestion? Again, it works on 5 other computers with no OneAPI2024. Note: my procedure working on all 5 PCs also involves installing certificates as suggested here: https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/HPC-Toolkit-installer-doesn-t-launch/m-p/1349833  and I replaced visual studio dll as suggested here https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/HPC-Toolkit-installer-doesn-t-launch/m-p/1349833.



LOG FILE BASEKIT INSTALL:

08/07/2024 13:53:40:018 : 26544 : MESSAGE : C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\Installer\installer.exe is run with arguments: --log-dir C:/Users/essie-adm-acanestrel/AppData/Local/Temp/intel_oneapi_installer/2024.08.07.13.53.12.363 --product-id intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product --product-ver 2021.2.0-2871 --package-path C:\Users\essie-adm-acanestrel\Downloads\w_BaseKit_p_2021.2.0.2871_offline (5)\packages
08/07/2024 13:53:40:018 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Installer is started in GUI mode
08/07/2024 13:53:40:018 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Installer executable location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\Installer\installer.exe, version is 4.0.6.0-432
08/07/2024 13:53:40:018 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Package manager executable location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\PackageManager\1.0\packagemanager.exe, version is 4.0.5-174
08/07/2024 13:53:40:018 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Product is set to intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product,v=2021.2.0-2871. Mode is set to install.
08/07/2024 13:53:40:318 : 26544 : ERROR : Signature verification failed.
Failed to validate signature of file C:\ProgramData\Intel\InstallerCache\intel.installer.oneapi.windows.installer\intel.oneapi.win.BaseKit.package,v=2024.0.0-49563\packagemanifest.json.
08/07/2024 13:53:40:318 : 26544 : ERROR : Failed to load package.
Try to download full installer package from remote source again and re-start installation.
08/07/2024 13:53:40:337 : 26544 : ERROR : Signature verification failed.
Failed to validate signature of file C:\ProgramData\Intel\InstallerCache\intel.installer.oneapi.windows.installer\intel.oneapi.win.HPCKit.package,v=2024.0.0-49588\packagemanifest.json.
08/07/2024 13:53:40:337 : 26544 : ERROR : Failed to load package.
Try to download full installer package from remote source again and re-start installation.
08/07/2024 13:53:41:038 : 24952 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for other install successfully checked
08/07/2024 13:53:41:043 : 24952 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for other Intel install successfully checked
08/07/2024 13:53:41:045 : 24952 : MESSAGE : All checks for preRequisite for supported operation system are passed
08/07/2024 13:53:57:972 : 14812 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for free disk space passed
08/07/2024 13:53:57:974 : 14812 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for permissions passed
08/07/2024 13:53:57:974 : 14812 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for other install successfully checked
08/07/2024 13:53:57:974 : 14812 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for other Intel install successfully checked
08/07/2024 13:53:58:025 : 14812 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for Visual Studio running with id = [visualStudioRunning.2019] passed
08/07/2024 13:53:58:025 : 14812 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for Visual Studio running with id = [visualStudioRunning.OtherUsers] passed
08/07/2024 13:53:58:113 : 26544 : MESSAGE : ISIP consent status is 'Yes'
08/07/2024 13:53:58:113 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Product installation directory is C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI
08/07/2024 13:53:58:114 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Product installation size required: 24018671383 bytes
08/07/2024 13:53:58:114 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Product will be (un)integrated with the following IDEs:
08/07/2024 13:53:58:114 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Microsoft Visual Studio* 2019
08/07/2024 13:53:58:114 : 26544 : MESSAGE : End of IDE list.
08/07/2024 13:53:58:130 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Graph State Dump.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product,v=2021.2.0-2871, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.basekit.getting_started,v=2021.2.0-2871, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.oneapi-common.vars,v=2021.2.0-156, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.oneapi-common.licensing,v=2021.2.0-156, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities,v=2021.2.0-426, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.common,v=2021.2.0-426, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.vs2017,v=2021.2.0-426, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-426, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.tbb.devel,v=2021.2.0-371, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.tbb.runtime,v=2021.2.0-371, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.condaindex,v=2021.2.0-85, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_vsix_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_vsix_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_bt_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_bt_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler,v=2021.2.0-616, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-dpcpp-common,v=2021.2.0-616, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common,v=2021.2.0-616, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.openmp,v=2021.2.0-616, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger,v=10.1.1-67, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.fee.vs2017,v=10.1.1-67, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.vsmi.vs2017,v=10.1.1-67, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.fee.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.vsmi.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-base-pro-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpl,v=2021.2.0-241, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.bt_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.bt_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_vsix_llvm_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_bt_llvm_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_bt_llvm_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_vsix_llvm_vs2017,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_bt_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_bt_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dnnl,v=2021.2.0-181, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.ipp.devel,v=2021.2.0-210, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.ipp.runtime,v=2021.2.0-210, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dal.devel,v=2021.2.0-366, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dal.runtime,v=2021.2.0-366, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.mkl.devel,v=2021.2.0-296, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.mkl.runtime,v=2021.2.0-296, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.vtune,v=2021.2.0-270, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.vtune.vsix,v=2021.2.0-270, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.vtune.vs2017,v=2021.2.0-270, Enabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.vtune.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-270, Enabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.advisor,v=2021.2.0-155, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.advisor.vsix,v=2021.2.0-155, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.advisor.vs2017,v=2021.2.0-155, Enabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.advisor.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-155, Enabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.common,v=2021.2.0-221, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.vs2017,v=2021.2.0-221, Disabled, Not Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-221, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.vpl,v=2021.2.2-209, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.python3,v=2021.2.0-198, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.mpi.runtime,v=2021.2.0-216, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
intel.oneapi.win.ippcp,v=2021.2.0-192, Enabled, Selected, Not Installed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

08/07/2024 13:53:58:135 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operations dump.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Updating package state...
Preparing installation...
Install intel.oneapi.win.oneapi-common.licensing,v=2021.2.0-156
Install intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.common,v=2021.2.0-426
Install intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-426
Install intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities,v=2021.2.0-426
Install intel.oneapi.win.condaindex,v=2021.2.0-85
Install intel.oneapi.win.tbb.runtime,v=2021.2.0-371
Install intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_vsix_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243
Install intel.oneapi.win.tbb.devel,v=2021.2.0-371
Install intel.oneapi.win.openmp,v=2021.2.0-616
Install intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.fee.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.vsmi.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger,v=10.1.1-67
Install intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common,v=2021.2.0-616
Install intel.oneapi.win.cpp-base-pro-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616
Install intel.oneapi.win.cpp-dpcpp-common,v=2021.2.0-616
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpl,v=2021.2.0-241
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243
Install intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243
Install intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler,v=2021.2.0-616
Install intel.oneapi.win.ipp.runtime,v=2021.2.0-210
Install intel.oneapi.win.ipp.devel,v=2021.2.0-210
Install intel.oneapi.win.dal.runtime,v=2021.2.0-366
Install intel.oneapi.win.dal.devel,v=2021.2.0-366
Install intel.oneapi.win.mkl.runtime,v=2021.2.0-296
Install intel.oneapi.win.mkl.devel,v=2021.2.0-296
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-221
Install intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.common,v=2021.2.0-221
Install intel.oneapi.win.vpl,v=2021.2.2-209
Install intel.oneapi.win.mpi.runtime,v=2021.2.0-216
Install intel.oneapi.win.python3,v=2021.2.0-198
Install intel.oneapi.win.ippcp,v=2021.2.0-192
Install intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product,v=2021.2.0-2871
Finalizing. It may take up to 10 minutes or more to integrate with your system, please do not interrupt the install process...
Updating package state...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

08/07/2024 13:53:58:445 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Start install/modify sequence execution.
08/07/2024 13:53:58:469 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'update_state.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428'.
08/07/2024 13:53:58:469 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'update_state.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:53:58:469 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'prepare.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428'.
08/07/2024 13:53:58:469 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'prepare.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:53:58:471 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.oneapi-common.licensing,v=2021.2.0-156'.
08/07/2024 13:53:59:052 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.oneapi-common.licensing,v=2021.2.0-156' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:53:59:052 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.common,v=2021.2.0-426'.
08/07/2024 13:53:59:721 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.common,v=2021.2.0-426' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:53:59:721 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-426'.
08/07/2024 13:54:08:813 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-426' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:54:08:813 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities,v=2021.2.0-426'.
08/07/2024 13:54:08:932 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dev-utilities,v=2021.2.0-426' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:54:08:932 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.condaindex,v=2021.2.0-85'.
08/07/2024 13:54:10:040 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.condaindex,v=2021.2.0-85' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:54:10:040 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.tbb.runtime,v=2021.2.0-371'.
08/07/2024 13:54:13:386 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.tbb.runtime,v=2021.2.0-371' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:54:13:386 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_vsix_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243'.
08/07/2024 13:54:14:218 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.vcperflib_vsix_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:54:14:218 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.tbb.devel,v=2021.2.0-371'.
08/07/2024 13:54:23:593 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.tbb.devel,v=2021.2.0-371' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:54:23:593 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.openmp,v=2021.2.0-616'.
08/07/2024 13:56:51:916 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.openmp,v=2021.2.0-616' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:56:51:916 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616'.
08/07/2024 13:56:55:718 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:56:55:718 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.fee.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67'.
08/07/2024 13:56:59:416 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.fee.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:56:59:416 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.vsmi.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67'.
08/07/2024 13:57:05:141 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger.vsmi.vs2019,v=10.1.1-67' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:57:05:141 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger,v=10.1.1-67'.
08/07/2024 13:57:08:993 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_debugger,v=10.1.1-67' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:57:08:993 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common,v=2021.2.0-616'.
08/07/2024 13:57:20:622 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.compilers-common,v=2021.2.0-616' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:57:20:622 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-base-pro-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616'.
08/07/2024 13:57:30:820 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-base-pro-common-runtime,v=2021.2.0-616' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:57:30:820 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-dpcpp-common,v=2021.2.0-616'.
08/07/2024 13:58:05:699 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-dpcpp-common,v=2021.2.0-616' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:05:699 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpl,v=2021.2.0-241'.
08/07/2024 13:58:06:884 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpl,v=2021.2.0-241' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:06:884 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243'.
08/07/2024 13:58:07:828 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler.ide.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:07:828 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243'.
08/07/2024 13:58:08:724 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.unique_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:08:724 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243'.
08/07/2024 13:58:09:522 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.cpp-compiler.ide.shared_vsix_llvm_vs2019,v=2021.2.0-243' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:09:522 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler,v=2021.2.0-616'.
08/07/2024 13:58:12:263 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp-compiler,v=2021.2.0-616' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:12:263 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.ipp.runtime,v=2021.2.0-210'.
08/07/2024 13:58:21:208 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.ipp.runtime,v=2021.2.0-210' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:21:208 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.ipp.devel,v=2021.2.0-210'.
08/07/2024 13:58:32:662 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.ipp.devel,v=2021.2.0-210' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:32:662 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dal.runtime,v=2021.2.0-366'.
08/07/2024 13:58:37:910 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dal.runtime,v=2021.2.0-366' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:58:37:910 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dal.devel,v=2021.2.0-366'.
08/07/2024 13:59:02:281 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dal.devel,v=2021.2.0-366' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:59:02:281 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.mkl.runtime,v=2021.2.0-296'.
08/07/2024 13:59:19:340 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.mkl.runtime,v=2021.2.0-296' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:59:19:340 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.mkl.devel,v=2021.2.0-296'.
08/07/2024 13:59:56:935 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.mkl.devel,v=2021.2.0-296' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 13:59:56:935 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-221'.
08/07/2024 14:00:04:256 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.vs2019,v=2021.2.0-221' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:00:04:257 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.common,v=2021.2.0-221'.
08/07/2024 14:00:09:027 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.dpcpp_ct.common,v=2021.2.0-221' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:00:09:027 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.vpl,v=2021.2.2-209'.
08/07/2024 14:00:13:709 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.vpl,v=2021.2.2-209' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:00:13:709 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.mpi.runtime,v=2021.2.0-216'.
08/07/2024 14:00:27:535 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.mpi.runtime,v=2021.2.0-216' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:00:27:535 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.python3,v=2021.2.0-198'.
08/07/2024 14:16:19:629 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.python3,v=2021.2.0-198' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:16:19:629 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.ippcp,v=2021.2.0-192'.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:513 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.ippcp,v=2021.2.0-192' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:513 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product,v=2021.2.0-2871'.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:800 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product,v=2021.2.0-2871' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:800 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'complete.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428'.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:895 : 14812 : WARNING : Product configuration is not finished successfully. Integration in IDE(s) might be in incomplete state or custom post-install/remove scripts might fail.
Details: Error: Sequence execution failed.

08/07/2024 14:16:23:895 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'complete.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428' execution is finished with status SuccessWithFail.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:895 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'update_state.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428'.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:913 : 14812 : MESSAGE : Operation 'update_state.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723053238130428' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 14:16:23:913 : 14812 : ERROR : Install sequence execution status: SuccessWithFail
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE : ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE : Anonymous statistics fields: 
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE :     EventId = 'install-min'
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE :     EventTime = ''
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE :     Id = 'intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product,v=2021.2.0-2871'
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE :     Message = '{  \"product_name\":\"[Windows] Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit 2021.2\",  \"lic_type\":\"\",   \"support_code\":\"\",   \"install_status\":\"4609\",   \"product_tag\":\"\"  }'
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE :     ProductId = '[Windows] Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit 2021.2'
08/07/2024 14:17:02:541 : 26544 : MESSAGE : ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


LOG FILE HPCKIT (only parts with errors since there is a stackoverflow limit on number of lines):

08/07/2024 15:09:01:666 : 13596 : MESSAGE : C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\Installer\installer.exe is run with arguments: --log-dir C:/Users/essie-adm-acanestrel/AppData/Local/Temp/intel_oneapi_installer/2024.08.07.15.08.51.560 --product-id intel.oneapi.win.hpckit.product --product-ver 2021.2.0-2901 --package-path C:\Users\essie-adm-acanestrel\Downloads\w_HPCKit_p_2021.2.0.2901_offline\packages
08/07/2024 15:09:02:021 : 13596 : ERROR : Signature verification failed.
Failed to validate signature of file C:\ProgramData\Intel\InstallerCache\intel.installer.oneapi.windows.installer\intel.oneapi.win.BaseKit.package,v=2024.0.0-49563\packagemanifest.json.
08/07/2024 15:09:02:021 : 13596 : ERROR : Failed to load package.
Try to download full installer package from remote source again and re-start installation.
08/07/2024 15:09:02:024 : 13596 : ERROR : Signature verification failed.
Failed to validate signature of file C:\ProgramData\Intel\InstallerCache\intel.installer.oneapi.windows.installer\intel.oneapi.win.HPCKit.package,v=2024.0.0-49588\packagemanifest.json.
08/07/2024 15:09:02:024 : 13596 : ERROR : Failed to load package.
Try to download full installer package from remote source again and re-start installation.
08/07/2024 15:09:02:769 : 28284 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for other install successfully checked
08/07/2024 15:09:02:774 : 28284 : MESSAGE : PreRequisite for other Intel install successfully checked
08/07/2024 15:09:02:780 : 28284 : MESSAGE : All checks for preRequisite for supported operation system are passed
08/07/2024 15:09:04:732 : 13596 : MESSAGE : The following products are installed by the moment:
Id: intel.oneapi.win.basekit.product, name: Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit, version: 2021.2, installation directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI
End of installed products list.
Details: Error: Sequence execution failed.

08/07/2024 15:10:03:045 : 24976 : MESSAGE : Operation 'complete.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723057754384639' execution is finished with status SuccessWithFail.
08/07/2024 15:10:03:045 : 24976 : MESSAGE : Starting execution of operation 'update_state.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723057754384639'.
08/07/2024 15:10:03:057 : 24976 : MESSAGE : Operation 'update_state.operation.intel.sessionmanifest.1723057754384639' execution is finished with status Success.
08/07/2024 15:10:03:057 : 24976 : ERROR : Install sequence execution status: SuccessWithFail
---------------------------------------------------------


The formatting of your post is really terrible. Please use code formatting for listings. Quotation formatting is an alternative. I suggest splitting the text into paragraphs for readibility.

It brings peace to my mind to know that the intel products and libraries are now free. Now you have installation/compilation/linking problem as soon you change a minor version of visual studio or even if you buy yourself a new mouse, but at least you are not paying. I could not recall how much time I have spent on intel forums regarding the same issues than you face, with answers from Intel going in circle, them just waiting for me to go on vacation for the thread to be with no updates for two weeks to be able to close it. But at least I came across Steve Lionel. :)
